# Slow TTFB / Server Response time under ManagePipelineHandler Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

Every time I run the homepage of the project I'm working with, it takes so much time to load (6-8 seconds page load time). And checking with webpagetest.org, the initial request takes more than 5000ms or 5seconds for the TTFB.

Environment Set-up:

- ASP.Net MVC
- IIS 8.5

Upon thorough investigation and checking the IIS tracing Logs, the long wait happens under the **ManagePipelineHandler** Module with 7515ms/7.5seconds (it consistently happens with **AspNetPagePreInitEnter**, **AspNetPageInitEnter** and **AspNetPageInitLeave**). Sample on the IIS trace log below:

[IIS Trace Logs where the hang happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcJlB.png)

And as I search on what does the hang on this ASP.NET events means, but I can't find any concrete answer on what causes this hang or why this hang happens.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169354/Pre-compiled-Razor-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC Keep in mind ASP.NET MVC by default uses runtime compilation so your view pages are taking time to be compiled when requested. Enable pre-compilation and see if you can reduce the cost.

Comment: Is the application deployed on the server or you're running this on your local machine? And how complex is the home page?

Comment: @JerdineSabio, yes this already in the server and its not that complex, I have already check the sql server for possible hang and what queries that might have caused the hang but all queries when the request was made were fast (40-80ms).

Comment: @LexLi, will check on that. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could try to disable anti-virus.

To figure out the root cause, it is recommended to dump file because the long wait happend in ManagePipelineHandler.

We may need to capture 2-3 dump files by generating a dump every 2 second.
Then we can compare the managed call stack. It will tell us what the thread is doing. We can improve the peformance only when we know what it was doing.

If you are not sure how to analyze dump file, then you could try

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210

If you know how to analyze a dump file, then you could try mex extension with WINDBG.

**!mex.aspxpagesext** will show all current requests hand its thread.

As long as we know the thread ID, we can use **mex.clrstack2**! to show the managed call stack